# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,

Tags: java, neo4j

I use neo4j-enterprise-2.2.4

Please help me!Thanks all!

This is my errors information:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\neo4j\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.4\data\movie
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:366)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:181)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:71)
    at traverser.Traversals.startTraversing(Traversals.java:34)
    at traverser.Traversals.main(Traversals.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@455c33' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@1dbc8b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.1' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.5'.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:268)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:344)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 11 more
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>neo4j.embedded.myserver</groupId>
<artifactId>myserver</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myserver</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
<version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
<version>2.1.5</version>
<type>test-jar</type>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
<artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
<groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>tests</artifactId>
<version>2.1.5.25</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
<artifactId>assertj-neo4j</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The root cause in the stack trace is "Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.1' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.5'.", which suggests you're using a newer database than your code knows how to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Neo4J, but it seems your problem is related with version mismatching.

Your log says you are accessing a `neo4j-enterprise-2.2.4` instance located in your `d:` unit. But your `pom.xml` has configured dependency for 2.1.5 version.

Later, your log complains about a mismatching in `NodeStore`:

> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. **Expected 'v0.A.1'** but file is version **'NodeStore v0.A.5'**

I found similar bug (*Although that bug is the opposite, the dependency is newer than nodestore*) on github [here](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/issues/101) and it is solved by means of matching versions (*or upgrading `nodesotre` but that is not your case*), so I think you have to upgrade your dependency to 2.2.4.

Hoep it helps.